# An error in tesseract OCR in VB-NET at new image

Tags: .net, vb.net, ocr, tesseract

I have added Tesseract from Emgu in Visual Basic .NET VS 2017. 
I have this code giving error at NEW Image with the message too arguments for this method:

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(picStc1))   'error too arguments
    RichTextBox1.Text = OCRz.GetBoxText
```

End Sub

It supposed will  make OCR, but it gives error just in creating the image.
I am working VS 2017 CE with .NET 4.5, I tried 3.5 before but it still happens.